# .info styles load before base theme

Tags: theming

I have a base theme and a sub-theme. The sub-theme specifies a single styles.css in the *.info file. The base theme provides CDN css stylesheets, via this hook:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$css) {

  drupal_add_css('http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css', array(
    'group' => CSS_THEME,
    'preprocess' => FALSE
  ));

  drupal_add_css('http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/grids-responsive-old-ie-min.css', array(
    'group' => CSS_THEME,
    'browsers' => array('IE' => 'lte IE 8'),
    'preprocess' => FALSE
  ));

  drupal_add_css('http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/grids-responsive-min.css', array(
    'group' => CSS_THEME,
    'browsers' => array('IE' => 'gt IE 8'),
    'preprocess' => FALSE
  ));

  drupal_add_css('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css', array(
    'group' => CSS_THEME,
    'preprocess' => FALSE
  ));  

}
```

The resulting HTML is this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">@import url("http://mysite.local/sites/all/themes/mytheme/styles.css?nezret");</style>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css?nezret" media="all">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/grids-responsive-min.css?nezret" media="all">
```

I need the @import to come in dead last in rendered order -- otherwise it seems the base theme styles are overriding my theme specific styless...

I have tried to correct this in the sub--theme by doing:

```
  function MYTHEME_css_alter(&$css) {

    foreach($css as $key => $value) {
      if($key == 'sites/all/themes/MYTHEME/styles.css') {
        $css[$key]['weight'] = 1000;
      }
    }

    uasort($css, 'drupal_sort_weight');

  }
```

This fixes the array but not the rendering order...WTF am I missing or doing wrong???

Comment: What exactly generates the line you are seeing? If CDN module is messing with you and breaks your theme, it is a matter for bugreport rather than for question here. And please avoid things like *"via CDN or otherwise"*. Be specific. If it's about CDN, ask about CDN. We can't really tell you what will work in **unspecified** situation. Not with any degree of certainty.

Comment: the order in which styles are being output is the question here...the styles.css I specify in theme.info I expect to render last to override the base theme...it is not...it appears before the <link> generated by base theme -- so base theme overrides anything in styles.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be curious to hear a alternative solution but this works too (albeit hackish):

I removed the reference to the stylesheet in *.info and simply added the call inside template.php:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
    drupal_add_css(path_to_theme().'/styles.css', array(
      'group' => CSS_THEME, 
      'preprocess' => FALSE
    ));
}
```